# Linux kernel "BUG: bad page state in process .." understanding

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have some proprietary kernel module.
And suddenly my system crashed in kdb with such bug:

```
BUG: bad page state in process <kworker_name> pfn:37751
page:<page_address> count:-1 mapcount:0 mapping:00000000 index:0x0
...
page dumped because: nonzero _count
```

So how should one understand what exactly does it mean? Unfortunately I can't find any info in the Internet about this bug.
What does `pfn:37751` and `count:-1` mean? What conclusions can be drawn?
Sorry if obvious.

Comment: **PFN** stands for *Page Frame Number*. Basically it's a page address in physical memory.

Comment: @0andriy thanks. Can `count:-1` indicate some double-free issue?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Linux MM. Sorry.

Comment: To help debug the problem, try building the kernel with CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL and CONFIG_DEBUG_VM and maybe some other CONFIG_DEBUG_VM_* configuration options turned on.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, I have allocated a buffer in kernel space and mapped to user space with remap_pfn_range(). On unmap(), I get this error. I have also observed this happens only when I allocate/map/unmap more than one page. Were you able to resolve this?